# How to denoise when baking into vertex color (color attributes)

Tags: baking, vertex-colors, denoise

I've been searching for quite a while for a solution for this but haven't been able to find anything.

As part of custom level making for the PC port of jak and daxter, the vertex colors are used as the baked lighting. However, simply baking with cycle into the color attribute in blender gives some very very noisy results which since it's applied on the vertex color of somewhat lowpoly models, make that noise very visible and looks really bad in game.

Increasing the sample count does help but even going pretty high still doesn't give great result in the darker areas. It also increase the render time far too much.

The only option I've had so far is to manually smooth it out with the blur tool in vertex painting. This is both extra manual work and also doesn't give the best result as both shadows and highlight then bleed into near areas.

Is there any other possible solution for my problem?